# My SQL Query Seems to be in a loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that lists items in my inventory, the `total quantity on hand`, `ordered qty` and `ship date`.

```
    +-------+-----------+------------+----------+
    | Item  | QtyOnHand | QtyOrdered | ShipDate |
    +-------+-----------+------------+----------+
    | Itema | 100       | 80         | 3/4/14   |
    | Itemb | 80        | 220        | 3/8/14   |
    | Itema | 100       | 80         | 3/10/14  |
    | Itemb | 80        | 100        | 3/12/14  |
    +-------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

I'm trying to create a query that will roll through sales orders by item in date (PromiseDate)order. With a known inventory amount (QtyOnHand) that subtracts the QtyOrdered amount for each order and keeps a running total of the QtyOnHand after subtracting the QtyOrdered and only writes to my table when the QtyOnHand is < 1 that way I know the date e specific item will be out of inventory.

After processing the follow data my new table should contain two records, one for each item representing the date that item would run out of inventory.

Please Help.
Thank you

Ken

```
CREATE TABLE #OverInv (Item VARCHAR(15), PromiseDate DATETIME, QtyOnHand INT, QtyOrdered INT, TotalOver INT) 
DECLARE @Item VARCHAR(15),
 @PromiseDate DATETIME,
 @QtyOrdered INT,
 @QtyOnHand INT,
 @CurrentItem VARCHAR(15),
 @TotalOver INT 

 SET @TotalOver = 0
 SET @CurrentItem = 0

 DECLARE rt_cursor CURSOR 
 FOR 
 SELECT Item, PromiseDate, QtyOrdered, QtyOnHand 
 FROM Inventory 

 OPEN rt_cursor 

 FETCH NEXT FROM rt_cursor INTO @Item,@PromiseDate,@QtyOrdered,@QtyOnHand 
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

IF @CurrentItem = 0
  BEGIN 
    SET @CurrentItem = @Item
    SET @TotalOver = (@QtyOnHand - @QtyOrdered)

    IF @TotalOver < 1 
       BEGIN
          INSERT #OverInv VALUES (@Item,@PromiseDate,@QtyOnHand,@QtyOrdered,@TotalOver) 
          FETCH NEXT FROM rt_cursor INTO @Item,@PromiseDate,@QtyOrdered,@QtyOnHand 
          SET @TotalOver = 0
       END
    ELSE
       BEGIN
          FETCH NEXT FROM rt_cursor INTO @Item,@PromiseDate,@QtyOrdered,@QtyOnHand
       END
  END

IF @CurrentItem = @Item
  SET @TotalOver = (@TotalOver - @QtyOrdered)
  BEGIN
    IF @TotalOver < 1
       BEGIN
         INSERT #OverInv VALUES (@Item,@PromiseDate,@QtyOnHand,@QtyOrdered,@TotalOver) 
         FETCH NEXT FROM rt_cursor INTO @Item,@PromiseDate,@QtyOrdered,@QtyOnHand 
         SET @TotalOver = 0
       END
    ELSE
       BEGIN
         FETCH NEXT FROM rt_cursor INTO @Item,@PromiseDate,@QtyOrdered,@QtyOnHand
       END
  END

IF @CurrentItem <> @Item
   SET @CurrentItem = @Item
   SET @TotalOver = (@QtyOnHand - @QtyOrdered)
   BEGIN  
     IF @TotalOver < 1 
        BEGIN
          INSERT #OverInv VALUES (@Item,@PromiseDate,@QtyOnHand,@QtyOrdered,@TotalOver) 
          FETCH NEXT FROM rt_cursor INTO @Item,@PromiseDate,@QtyOrdered,@QtyOnHand 
          SET @TotalOver = 0
        END
     ELSE
       BEGIN
         FETCH NEXT FROM rt_cursor INTO @Item,@PromiseDate,@QtyOrdered,@QtyOnHand
       END
   END


CLOSE rt_cursor 
DEALLOCATE rt_cursor 

SELECT * FROM #OverInv ORDER BY Item 

DROP TABLE #OverInv
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that without cursors. First you need to put your data in following format:

```
Item |  QtyOnHand  | Initial date
Item | -QtyOrdered | ShipDate
```

Then you need to sum it by item and date. Next you calculate running sum of the quantity. And finally select min date where quantity is negative. Here is the complete query:

```
with cte1 as
(
  -- assuming QtyOnHand is the same in all Inventory rows
  select Item, min(QtyOnHand) as QtyOnHand, min(ShipDate) as ShipDate 
  from Inventory
  group by Item

  union all

  select Item, -QtyOrdered as QtyOnHand, ShipDate 
  from Inventory
)
, cte2 as
(
  -- only one row per item and date
  select Item, SUM(QtyOnHand) as QtyOnHand, ShipDate
  from cte1
  group by Item, ShipDate
)
, cte3 as
(
  select 
    Item,
    SUM(QtyOnHand) OVER(partition by item order by ShipDate) as QtyOnHand,
    ShipDate
  from
    cte2
)
select Item, min(ShipDate) as ShipDate
from cte3
where QtyOnHand < 0
group by Item
```

SUM() OVER() requires SQL Server 2012 but there are other ways how to calculate running sum of course. Check the [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6cfd1/11/0).